# Get all products collection which have 5 star review

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog, review, ratings

I need to get all the products from my magento store, Which have

> 5 Star

reviews and rating.

Comment: Which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works for getting all products which has 5 star rating.

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->joinField('rating_score', 
                   'review_entity_summary', 
                   'rating_summary', 
                   'entity_pk_value=entity_id', 
                   array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),'rating_summary'=> 100),
                   'right'
);
```